# Black screen with colored dots when trying to boot from USB using rufus GPT partition on my laptop eMMC

Tags: windows-10, usb, gpt, black-screen-of-death, rufus

As I mentioned in the title, I'm trying to install Windows 10 on my Dell Inspirion 14 which only has a 32Gb eMMC (no HDD). I have been reading a lot of articles saying that I should run Rufus with these specs:

[image: Rufus settings]

I did, but now I'm getting this black screen with this colored dots when I boot from my USB:

[image: Black screen with this colored dots]

Please help, I have been looking for a solution for this problem for more than a week now, I'm desperate

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: just adding few keywords for future readers: I have encountered the same issue of dotted lines on HP pavilion DM4 with a USB drive prepared with rufus. @akeo's solved it!

Answer (score 12):

I've seen this before, so I'm pretty sure you are getting an improper display of [this screen](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/pbatard/rufus/images/legacy_boot.png).

You need to follow the [advice from the Rufus FAQ](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ#ERROR_BIOSLEGACY_BOOT_OF_UEFIONLY_MEDIA) and either recreate your media for BIOS boot or edit your UEFI settings to disable CSM/Legacy boot.

As to why your computer/display can't properly show a standard BIOS/Legacy screen, you'll have to ask your manufacturer...

Comment: I have the same problem. I followed your answer. It no longer displays the black dotted lines, but it still doesn't boot. It attempts for some seconds to read my USB drive, after which it skips and loads the defunct HDD.

Comment: Changing to MBR solved my problem.

Comment: It was already MBR, ticking option to add additional fixes for old BIOS fixed the problem.